# How to disable the copy popup inside a UIWebView in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios8

I have read several solutions on stackoverflow of which none work for iOS 8.1
I managed to disable a long press from this [uiwebview-without-copy-paste-when-displaying-pdf-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768194/uiwebview-without-copy-paste-when-displaying-pdf-files) but I can't get the popup which offers :"Open", "Add to Reading List" and "Copy" from URLs disabled.

```
//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/somePdf.pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.mainWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
[self.mainWebView.scrollView setBounces:NO];

self.mainWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
self.mainWebView.delegate = self;

//NSString * jsCallBack = @"window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();";
//[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
[self.mainWebView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self.mainWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.mainWebView loadRequest:requestURL];


UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil]; // allocating the UILongPressGestureRecognizer

longPress.allowableMovement=100; // Making sure the allowable movement isn't too narrow

longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.3; // This is important - the duration must be long enough to allow taps but not longer than the period in which the scroll view opens the magnifying glass

longPress.delegate=self; // initialization stuff
longPress.delaysTouchesBegan=YES;
longPress.delaysTouchesEnded=YES;

longPress.cancelsTouchesInView=YES; // That's when we tell the gesture recognizer to block the gestures we want

[self.mainWebView addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; // Add the gesture recognizer to the view and scroll view then release
[[self.mainWebView scrollView] addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

I have tested it on some random pdf, and the pdf text is not selectable thanks to the longPress gesture recognizer. However on a normal site it still allows the copy popup.

I will try to edit the web page with this [changeing web page settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview) but the answer is 3 years old...

Maybe I am on a whole wrong track? Should I try using a **WKWebView**?

Comment: No doubt you should use **WKWebView** at least if you want better performance and access to the latest web technologies **WebKit** supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to disable the system's copy/paste popup behaviour in your app, but you can disable this option directly from your web content using `-webkit-user-select: none` and you should do it only on single elements, not the whole document.

This is how Apple recommends it in one of their [Technical Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html):

> You can handle touches directly or even detect advanced gestures in
>   Safari on iOS, using the DOM Touch events touchstart, touchmove,
>   touchend, and touchcancel. Unlike mouse events which are emulated, DOM
>   Touch events are specifically designed to work with touch interfaces,
>   so their behavior is reliable and expected. For more information on
>   using touch events in web content for Safari on iOS, see the "Handling
>   Events" section of the Safari Web Content Guide, the Touch,
>   TouchEvent, and TouchList classes in the Safari DOM Additions
>   Reference, and the SlideMe sample code at the Safari Dev Center.
>
> Since touching and holding in Safari on iOS will invoke the
>   Cut/Copy/Paste dialog, you may also choose to disable selection on
>   user interface elements such as menus and buttons using
>   `-webkit-user-select: none`. It is important to only disable selection as needed on a per-element basis. Selection in webpages should never
>   be globally disabled.

Answer (score 3):

If you load your request to WebView, you can disable the javascript request. In my case, I use the following flow. Firstly you should add a UIWebViewDelegate delegate in a header file.

```
@interface StoreViewController : HomeButtonController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

and then you jump the implementation file and add this code inside the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     @"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     @"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

Comment: I am showing PDF in webview and this solution doesn't work :(

Comment: The above code only disable javascript on web view. What do you want? Showing PDF on web view or disable javascript

Comment: I am showing PDF and It has some deeplinks, on which when user do long press system action sheet with option Open/Copy appears. I don't want to show that as links are deep linked within app.

Comment: Could you add some information about your ios sdk version, and browser. Depands on your ios sdk or web browser version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple answer that works in iOS 12.0

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```