# How do I disable copy and paste (user selection) in UIWebviews

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiwebview

My problem is that I want to disable a user from copying and pasting in a UIWebView.

Comment: does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676369/how-to-disable-copy-and-paste-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516027

Swift version of the solution:

`// deactivate copy and paste
    for checkView in webView.subviews {
        if let scrollView = checkView as? UIScrollView {
            for checkView in scrollView.subviews {
                checkView.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            break
        }
    }`